# How to create HFS+ partition on Windows 7 machine

Tags: macos, filesystems, partitioning, hfs

I'm running Windows 7 and I would like to partition my D: volume and make it HFS+, but I cannot find any tool that will accomplish this.

Has anyone done this before? Is it possible? I have EaseUS Partition Master but it does not support HFS/HFS+.

Comment: With 510 reputation you must have learned already, that SO is about programming, haven't you?

Comment: Hehe :) u did it 508, sorry I completely forgot it, need to ask it somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/ will make HFS+ partitions. Just an FYI, `gparted` can only shrink, not enlarge, HFS+ partitions.

Comment: But I think it's the other way around... GParted can only shrink NOT enlarge HFS+ partitions.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy Right! Wow, 9 years later someone caught that...

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you had a HFS+ driver that hooks into the system properly (as opposed to hfs explorer), you could do it - I currently use a copy of [macdrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive) bundled with some other software, which gives me a right click and HFS+ format option.

Paragon [has another option](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/features.html) but I don't see any indication if it'll allow formatting.